# Configure a tomcat session manager to ignore particular requests

Tags: java, session, tomcat

I'm trying to configure a `context.xml` such that my custom AWS DynamoDB session manager doesn't attempt to create sessions for particular requests (e.g. mobile ones).

This seems like a natural enough role for a `Valve` entity. The valve listens for particular requests and sets some state that signals action or inaction to the rest of the session management system. However, I can't figure out where that state ought to be. Is there a consensus right way to do this?

Comment: It's the application that creates sessions. The session manager only manages them.

Answer (score 0):

Your need to find the place in your own application where the sessions are being created, and stop them from being created *there*. Unless you are using FORM authentication, Tomcat will never create a session for a request unless your application specifically calls `HttpServletRequest.getSession(true)`.